# Can I remove the My Boards organization

Tags: trello, trello-organization, trello-boards

Altough I really doubt it is possible, can I remove the "My Boards" organization in trello? This is where all boards are created by default but since I am very organized and order my boards by organizations this one is always on top, empty and anoying to me.

If I can't completely remove it for design reasons such as which organizatyion would be taken by default when I create a board, can I at least hide it somehow from my left side panel or boards overview?

Comment: This seems to be a feature request, which should be directed to Trello.

Comment: Actually I'd like to request that feature and if it was, I would be doing it on trello's website. But right now I'm not requesting anything I'm simply asking if the feature exists and if it does, where is it hidden because I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot remove the "My Boards" section. 
That section relates to boards not associated with any organization.

While you cannot remove the "My Boards" section from the "left side panel" you mention, you can minimize the appearance by

1. Click on the minus ("-") "Collapse section" icon to the right of "My Boards" in the left side panel.
2. Star boards there you use most frequently (or all) so they move up above the "Recent Boards" and "My Boards" sections.